# What is the limit to the number of questions I can ask on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

Is there a limit on the total number of questions a user can ask?

Comment: I think you can already find your answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: Hi Adalee, thank you for suggesting the page.

Comment: @rkj: so what part isn't clear to you? Please ask *specific questions*, we are not here to re-hash the documentation again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "On Stack Overflow, maximum of 6 questions per day, maximum of 50 questions per 30 days". That part, does that applies to all SO users ?

Comment: Personally, until the edit, it was a fair and specific question, and not deserving of -8 (and what will come); but then it got a bit out of hand with all the other questions and edits.

Comment: @rkj: that applies to all users, yes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no upper limit to how many questions a user can ask, but there are throttles on Stack Overflow - maximums of 6 a day and 50 per month.

There is, however, a question throttle - if a new user starts asking a lot of questions that are not well received (downvoted, flagged and possibly deleted), they will have to wait before they can ask their next question immediately (and if the next question is also not well received then the waiting period is longer, and so on).

If they keep on going like that, they can end up in an indefinite question block, where they can't ask any more questions, unless the improve their old questions enough (this is automated - no people involved).

Comment: So a user on SO can ask 6 questions in a day ?

Comment: @rkj - at most. They could be throttled before that, depending on how well (or badly) their other questions have been received.

Comment: Right, thank you for answering.

Comment: I can't imagine the possibility of being able to ask 6 on-topic questions in a single day.

Comment: @Oded, if the brief value reach a height level, does affect the limit? reach how high level will can not get a limit ?

Comment: @samoye - finding it very difficult to parse what you are asking. All I will say is - learn how to ask good questions - we provide [plenty of guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Oded, I means if someone get a high level reputation, such as you have 353k, do you still have that constraint？

Comment: @samoye - if I start asking bad questions? Sure, I expect I would get into a question block.