# Is there a limit to the number of questions? How can I ask freely?

Tags: discussion

I'm studying programming now, and I just want post questions about programming several times a day. But this website lets me upload only one question a day.

How can I freely ask multiple questions a day?

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [help] and search through [meta] will give you the answer.

Comment: Question about this site have to be asked over at [meta].

Comment: See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

Comment: This site is not a good site if your desire is to do nothing but ask questions about whatever comes to mind. This site is a *great* site if you want to **find answers** to your questions when they come to mind. Note the difference in intent. Stack Overflow exists to create a knowledge base everyone can use to find their answer **not** to answer everyone's questions over and over again. Please keep that in mind as you continue your journey on this site. And welcome to Stack Overflow :).

Comment: The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of high-quality programming knowledge, not to be a free help desk. Questions should be well-researched, well-written and useful to other visitors also. This takes time and since [urgency for the asker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/11682469) is of no relevance to us, just take your time to prepare your high-quality contributions and spread them out over several days.

Comment: And if you are in a need to ask many questions as part of your study... that is why people tend to go to school or follow courses. It gives them that ability, among other benefits that greatly aid the success rate and usefulness of the study. It is an investment that is still well worth it today.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Bunker down with your fellow students and attack the problems in teams. Not only does this better reflect what'll happen to you as a professional programmer, the extra brains really help understand the material. What you understand, you pass on to the rest of the group. What they understand comes back your way.

Comment: And get good books. Don't try to learn programming from the Internet. You get three broad types of people posting how-tos on the Internet: folks who know so little that they can't grasp how bad they are,  folks who know too much and can't communicate it effectively, and folks who know what they are doing and can communicate it. You'll find very few of the latter, and until you know enough of the fundamentals to tell the first from the other two, you'll find yourself learning from a lot of crappy programmers. There are a LOT more crappy programmers than good programmers on the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the answer by Oded at this related question: [What is the limit to the number of questions I can ask on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293756/what-is-the-limit-to-the-number-of-questions-i-can-ask-on-stack-overflow)

There is an upper limit of 6 questions a day and 50 per month, but this is reduced if the system determines that your questions are not well received by the community. This will happen if they are downvoted, closed, flagged or deleted. In the worst case you may be limited to 1 question every 6 months.

Comment: Side note: attempt to fix poorly received questions before deleting them. Stack Overflow includes deleted questions in the posting eligibility calculations, so even though you get some reputation back by deleting a question, the question may still be a deadweight holding you back from asking questions. Out of sight its merits will never get a chance to be re-evaluated. If you delete, fix the question, if possible, and undelete. Note that some questions (question based on a trivial typo, for example) probably can't be adequately fixed to a point where it has value to the community.